# (Hadn't got/didn't have) to have got

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives

I know that "had to have +past participle" can be used for deduction about the past, so when it comes to the negative, can I use both "hadn't got" and "didn't have" + past participle (to mean that something can't have happened)?

> I knew that my friend never got lost in the forest, but that time, he'd been there abnormally long, so when my mom said, "He will have got lost," I said that he (hadn't got/didn't have) to have got lost.

Comment: Note that in American English, we would more likely say *He will have got**ten** lost*. And we probably wouldn't use *will have* like that... *He must have gotten lost.*

Answer (score 0):

## “get to have” *vs* “hadn’t got/gotten to” *vs* “didn’t have to”

> I knew that my friend never got lost in the forest, but that time, he'd been there abnormally long, so when my mom said, “He will have got lost,” I said that he [**hadn’t got / didn’t have**] to have got lost.

English multi-word verb constructions are especially hard for learners, even if you are yourself a native speaker of another language that’s descended from ancestral Proto-Indo-European just like English is. It seems to me that you do already have a pretty good but not yet perfect grasp of the nuances in these sorts of construction that so often plague learners, and that you’re just trying to fine-tune your understanding of them.

First, let’s take for granted that these five statements all mean essentially the
same thing as one another because they’re all about the speaker’s belief in the strong
likelihood of some past event having actually occurred:

1. I think he got lost.
2. He will have gotten lost.
3. He must have gotten lost.
4. He has to have gotten lost.
5. He has got to have gotten lost.
   (Those last ones sure do have a lot of *get* verbs in them, but they’re
   used quite differently.  *To get lost* is *to become lost*, but *to
   have **got** to do something* is just *must do something*, making
   *he has got to go* the same as *he has to go* and *he must go*.
   Although I don’t **think** you’re confusing the “likely”
   or “epistemic” senses of the *have got to do something* periphrastic
   modal construction with its “obligatory” or "deontic” senses, the
   *get* there is nevertheless totally different from how it’s used
   in *to get lost*.)

Given that, I **believe** that the heart of your question then boils down to how best to negate that statement of belief or likelihood — or
at least how to say that his having gotten lost isn’t the **only**
possible explanation that one should consider.  So for doing that, your first choice is wrong — because
for the negation you cannot say:

6. ❌ He had not **got** to have gotten lost.

Because that’s not grammatical for the sense you want. It’s possible to use *hadn’t got to* but not in the sense you desire here so if you did use it, it would have a different meaning. That’s because *had not got to do something* means *did not get to do something*: the opportunity never presented itself or perhaps that it was not acted on when it did show up. So *to get to do something* isn’t what you want here.

What you need is to use *do*-support (by way of *did* marked in the past tense) for
the *to have to do something* construction. You need to say it this way
instead:

7. ✅ He did not **have** to have gotten lost.

As in:

8. He doesn’t necessarily **have** to have gotten lost ....

Perhaps followed by one of these using *to have an accident*:

9. ... because maybe he had some kind of accident.
10. ... because he may have had some kind of accident.
11. ... because he might have had some kind of accident.

Or by using *to get into an accident*, such as with one of these:

12. ... because maybe he got into some kind of accident.
13. ... because he may have gotten into some kind of accident.
14. ... because he might have gotten into some kind of accident.

---

### Reduction and devoicing of weak forms

Note that here the *have* in *to have* before a past participle is normally
pronounced like *of* is, and the whole thing may be [tuv] or [təv] in
connected speech. That’d because although the first *have* needs the strong
form and devoices to [ˈhæftə], but the second one needs the weak form [əv].

## See Also

See also the related questions about:

- [has to have](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22has+to+have%22), [had to have](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22had+to+have%22), [have to have](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22have+to+have%22)
- [have got, have gotten](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22have+gotten%22)
- [must have gotten](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22must+have+gotten%22)
- [have had to have](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22have+had+to+have%22)

Comment: You are so kind and intelligent! I am going to never forget your help! You are a truly wise owl!